# SSRS comparing dates in an expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have some basic expressions to highlight certain fields:

```
=IIF(Fields!Failure.Value > 0, "Red", "Transparent")
```

However, I have another field that contains dates in the following format:

```
22/08/2016 22/08/2016 - each field can contain multiple dates.
```

This is stored in SQL as a VARCHAR.

I need to run a similar expression in my report to achieve the following:

If the date is 1 day older than the date the report is run, highlight the field. If the date is greater than 1 day older, highlight the field a different colour.

I#m familiar with basic expressions, but I can't think of an easy way to obtain the current date, and then compare between the two.

Comment: Use date data type, not varchar, to store dates.

Comment: I cannot do that unfortunately, as the single contains multiple date entries.

Comment: That's an even worse design issue... Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Can you include the SQL query that generates the dataset this report is using?  Also, what is the significance of each date in the field?  Are they always the same as per your example, or are they distinct dates with specific, individual meanings?

Comment: Each date has relevance, ultimately I would need to check each in turn and produce an aggregate result (i.e. if any of the given dates do not much the current date, do something)

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting if one date in the list is 1 day older than today and another is more than one day older?

Comment: Field can background to "Red".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you really shouldn't be using hacks like this...

But, this should work for you:

```
=iif(Len(Replace(Replace(Fields!DateField.Value," ",""), Format(Today, "dd/MM/yyyy"),"")) = 0, "Transparent" ,iif(Len(Replace(Replace(Replace(Fields!DateField.Value," ",""), Format(Today, "dd/MM/yyyy"),""), Format(Today().AddDays(-1), "dd/MM/yyyy"),"")) = 0, "Green", "Red"))
```

Essentially, remove the joining character (in this case, space) and then replace all instances of the current date in the given format.  If there are any characters left, you have a date that doesn't match today.  Then take that value and repeat for any instances of yesterday.

**Obviously this will fall down if your date formatting changes.**
But then you already knew that comparing dates as strings was a bad idea, right...

Comment: I get an error when trying to run the report (I have replaced the DateField.Value with my dataset value).

Comment: Please paste in both the error message and your expression.

Comment: Also, did you replace both instances of the DateField?

Comment: Ignore, this works perfectly, it was just me being "special". Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Split function to generate an array of values. Of course, you'll still need to select one of those to test. The following may get you going again.

```
=Iif(
    CDate(
        Split(
            "21/08/2016, 22/08/2016",
            ","
        ).GetValue(0)
    ) < Today,
    "True",
    "False"
)
```

If, however, you are dealing with a date string that can contain any number of dates and you to test all of them then a simple SSRS expression won't handle that. Fortunately we can use a bit of custom code.

Right-click the report background and select report properties. Click the 'Code' item and paste the following into code box

```
Public Function TestDate(DateString As String) As String
    Dim DatesArray() As String = Split(DateString)
    Dim ReturnValue As String = "Transparent"
    For Each d As String In DatesArray
        If Date.Parse(d) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Date.Today) Then
            ReturnValue = "Red"
        End If
        If Date.Parse(d) < DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Date.Today) Then
            ReturnValue = "DarkRed"
        End If
    Next
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

Now change the expression as below

```
=Code.TestDate("21/08/2016 22/08/2016")
```

I've used Date.Today in the VB to restrict the comparison of the date to the day. If you wanted to be more precise ie: the exact time, use Date.Now instead

Comment: Going by the format in the example given, you would need to split on the space, not a comma.

Comment: It would be on a space, however, I cannot hard code the dates into the Split(). How would I fill this automatically with all values of the given field?

Comment: So replace the hard string of dates with your dataset field eg Split(Fields!MyFieldName.Value)

Comment: Each date has relevance, ultimately I would need to check each in turn and produce an aggregate result (i.e. if any of the given dates do not much the current date, do something)

Comment: Pnp, see above for a possible better solution

Comment: Thanks! How would that work to dictate the background colour for that expression?

Comment: @PnP  This solution is slightly over engineered for what you need, as this can be done using Expressions, per my answer.

Comment: Function altered to return a color string value instead of a Boolean so it can be used directly. @iamdave yes it is a bit more in depth, but it is immune to date formatting changes as that is handled by .Net

Comment: @PaulBambury  True.  I'm curious though if the .Net Parse will be able to accurately determine between `1/2/2016` meaning January or February, given that you haven't specified a particular format to follow.

Comment: @iamdave That would depend on the value of the Report.Language property. Setting this appropriately (eg "en-GB") will guarantee the correct format